# How to install iF.SVNAdmin on ubuntu

Tags: php, svn, ubuntu, open-basedir

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients the web interface [iF.SVNAdmin](http://svnadmin.insanefactory.com/) can be installed on a linux OS.

I want to use it as web interface for subversion repositories on a ubuntu vserver with running apache and php (the only two listed requirements on the product's website), but I fail on entering a path to the svn executable.

In the configuration template there are paths to a svn.exe and svnadmin.exe - looks like windows only.

Is it possible to use iF.SVNAdmin on ubuntu and if yes: how?

// EDIT:
I finally got to it: the path to the linux svn and svnadmin binaries (/usr/bin/svn and /usr/bin/svnadmin) need not only be configured in the config.ini (what I did), but the path /usr/bin/ has to be in the php open_basedir configuration. At least the configuration screen opened now, and I can proceed configurating If.SVNAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For closing reasons, again the answer:

- It is possible to install iF.SVNAdmin on Ubuntu
- The apache user needs access to the svn and svnadmin binaries (located in /usr/bin/)
- The binaries have to be within the php open_basedir path(s).